# Finding the roots of an equation numerically returns the initial guess

Tags: python, cubic

I am trying to find the root of a cubic equation using `fsolve`. This is my code:

```
from scipy import *
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#These are all parameters
g = 5.61
gamma = 6.45
kappa = 6.45
J = 6.45
rs = 10.0                        
m = 5.0*10**(-11)
wm = 2*3.14*23.4
r2 = np.linspace(0, 0.02, 1000)
deltaW = 0                     

A = 1j*g**2*(kappa + 1j*deltaW)*r2*r2/(m*wm**2)
B = J**2 + (1j*deltaW - gamma)*(1j*deltaW + kappa)
C = A + B
D = abs(C)*r2 - J*np.sqrt(2*kappa)*rs

def func(x):
        D = abs(C)*r2 - J*np.sqrt(2*kappa)*rs
        return D

x0  = fsolve(func, 0.0)
print x0
plt.plot(r2, D)
plt.show()
```

I can see from the plot that there is at least one r2 that makes D zero. However, the return value x0 I get from fsolve is always the guess value I set.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Really sorry for such a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing to `fsolve` a function that isn't a function at all: it doesn't do anything with the inputs `x`. Yet, `fsolve` needs that, because it will test a series of values and each time check the return value from the function call with that test value. In your case, `func(x)` never changes, so `fsolve` stops with an error message of

> The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the improvement from the last ten iterations.

You could see that message if you would add `full_output=True` in the call to `fsolve`.

To solve it, define your function like this:

```
def func(x):
    A = 1j*g**2*(kappa + 1j*deltaW)*x*x/(m*wm**2)
    B = J**2 + (1j*deltaW - gamma)*(1j*deltaW + kappa)
    C = A + B
    D = abs(C)*x - J*np.sqrt(2*kappa)*rs
    return D
```